# how can i call setter without calling <f:viewparam> converter?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

i am using jsf 2.1.1 and primefaces 3.0.M4. i have a sample jsf page that used to post country comments. i use f:viewparam tag with converter to view country pages. here are the codes:

country.xhtml:

```
<f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="country" value="#{countryBean2.selectedCountry}" converter="countryConverter" required="true"/>
    </f:metadata>

    <h:head>
        <title>Country</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <h:form id="form">
            <h:outputText value="#{countryBean2.selectedCountry.countryName}" />
            <br/><br/>
            <h:outputText value="Comment:" />
            <h:inputText value="#{countryBean2.comment}" />
            <br/>
            <p:commandButton value="Send" action="#{countryBean2.sendComment}" update="@this" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
```

CountryBean2.java:

```
@Named("countryBean2")
@SessionScoped
public class CountryBean2 implements Serializable {
    private EntityCountry selectedCountry;
    private String comment;

    public EntityCountry getSelectedCountry() { return selectedCountry; }
    public void setSelectedCountry(EntityCountry newValue) { selectedCountry = newValue; }

    public String getComment() { return comment; }
    public void setComment(String newValue) { comment = newValue; }

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testPU");

    public void sendComment() {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        try {
            FacesMessage msg = null;
            EntityTransaction entr = em.getTransaction();
            boolean committed = false;
            entr.begin();
            try {
                EntityCountryComment c = new EntityCountryComment();
                c.setCountry(selectedCountry);
                c.setComment(comment);
                em.persist(c);
                committed = true;
                msg = new FacesMessage();
                msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO);
                msg.setSummary("Comment was sended");
            } finally {
                if (!committed) entr.rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

CountryConverter.java:

```
public class CountryConverter implements Converter {
    public static EntityCountry country = new EntityCountry();

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testPU");


    @Override
    public EntityCountry getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM EntityCountry c WHERE c.countryName = :countryName")
                .setParameter("countryName", value);
        country = (EntityCountry) query.getSingleResult();
        return country;
    }


    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        EntityCountry c = (EntityCountry) value;
        return c.getCountryName();
    }
}
```

i want to call "setComment" setter without calling CountryConverter, when i am using commandbutton to post comment. how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's by design of the `<f:viewParam>` component. It will convert the request parameter and set the property on *every* HTTP request, also on postbacks. In order to change this behaviour, you would need to extend `<f:viewParam>` with a custom component which doesn't remember the initial request parameter in its state. It's relatiely simple, instead of delegating the `setSubmittedValue()` and `getSubmittedValue()` to `StateHelper`, you just need to make it an instance variable. This is described in detail in [this blog](http://jdevelopment.nl/stateless-stateful-jsf-view-parameters/).

```
@FacesComponent("com.my.UIStatelessViewParameter")
public class UIStatelessViewParameter extends UIViewParameter {

    private String submittedValue;

    @Override
    public void setSubmittedValue(Object submittedValue) {  
        this.submittedValue = (String) submittedValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String getSubmittedValue() { 
        return submittedValue;
    }   
}
```

[OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) has an ready-to-use component for this in flavor of [`<o:viewParam>`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/vdldoc/current/o/viewParam.html). Here is the [live example](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/viewParam).